# how to pass variable value to specific cell in tkinter grid

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

Respected Sir
I have grid ( 5 row and 5 column) that enter
i try to give value by variable to specific cell see my code

please guide me which one is the right code
`entry(1,1).set_ value = 'testing data' grid(1,1).set_ value = 'testing data' root. grid[(1,1)].configure(text="the new text in specific cell ")`

Please give me the idea how i give the data to specific cell

This is my code:

```py
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk( ) 

def callback(*args): 
    print("testing data hi") 
    root.widget[(1,1)].configure(text="the new text in specific cell ") 
    root.bind("<F2>", callback)
    b=0 
    for r in range(5): 
        for c in range(5): 
            b=b+1 
            Entry(root, text=str(b), borderwidth=1 ).grid(row=r,column=c) 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: # this is my code
from tkinter import *
root = Tk( )

def callback(*args):
    print("testing data hi")
    root.widget[(1,1)].configure(text="the new text in specific cell ")

root.bind("<F2>", callback)

b=0
for r in range(5):
      for c in range(5):
         b=b+1
         Entry(root, text=str(b),  borderwidth=1 ).grid(row=r,column=c)
         
root.mainloop()

Comment: [edit] your question and add the information there, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
def callback(*args):
    EntryObjects = []
    b=0 
    for r in range(5): 
        for c in range(5): 
            b=b+1
            entry = Entry(root, borderwidth=1 )
            entry.insert(0, b)
            entry.grid(row=r,column=c)
            EntryObjects.append(entry)
    
    EntryObjects[1].insert(0, "text")
    EntryObjects[4].insert(0, 'the new text in specific cell' )
            
callback()
root.mainloop()
```

And also using a Name and a for-loop

```
def callback(*args):
    b=0 
    for r in range(5): 
        for c in range(5): 
            b=b+1
            entry = Entry(root, borderwidth=1, name=str(b))
            entry.insert(0, b)
            entry.grid(row=r,column=c)
    
    for child in root.winfo_children():
        if child.winfo_name() == '6':
            child.insert(1, 'Entry was named 6')
            
callback()
root.mainloop()
```